# In what condition can memcached run into allocation failure

Tags: memcached, allocation

each slab class has at least one page, and when there's no memory available to allocate, it will evict items in the "tails" list. So why can it run into MEMCACHED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILURE state?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a libmemcached state, not a memcached state. In any case it would occur when the application requests memory from the underlying allocator (malloc) and malloc returns no heap memory. Since the request for memory cannot be completed you would likely get an error like this since the application would not be able to proceed with your request.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when client call libmemcached.libmemcached throw exception include several cases:

1 realloc, malloc, calloc

2 see source code segment as follow:

```
...
new_size= sizeof(char) * (size_t)((adjust * MEMCACHED_BLOCK_SIZE) + string->current_size);
if (new_size < need)
  return MEMCACHED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILURE;
...
```

fully it could not happen